# Sublime Text 3 Better Coffee​Script package

Tags: coffeescript, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I've used the [Better Coffee​Script](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Better%20CoffeeScript) package for some time now. Today it is not working anymore. No syntax highlighting, also I can't find it under Package Controll when I'm trying to install it again. Any ideas? Thank!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, the package was disabled (have no idea why). **Package Controll: Enable Package -> Better CoffeeScript** resolved my problem.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and solved this way:

**Package Control > Disable Package > Better CoffeeScript**

and then

**Package Control > Enable Package > Better CoffeeScript**